# Difference in "delegate call via assembly"

Tags: solidity, assembly, delegatecall

I came across different versions of `delegatecall` via assembly and I tried all of them - no different result so far. How do they differ and which is the best version to use?

OpenZeppelin version:

```
assembly {
    let ptr := mload(0x40)
    calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
    let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
    let size := returndatasize
    returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

    switch result
    case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
    default { return(ptr, size) }
}
```

MakerDAO version:

```
assembly {
    let succeeded := delegatecall(sub(gas, 5000), _target, add(_calldata, 0x20), mload(_calldata), 0, 0)
    let size := returndatasize

    response := mload(0x40)
    mstore(0x40, add(response, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), not(0x1f))))
    mstore(response, size)
    returndatacopy(add(response, 0x20), 0, size)

    switch iszero(succeeded)
    case 1 {
        revert(add(response, 0x20), size)
    }
}
```

Simple version:

```
assembly {
    let succeeded := delegatecall(sub(gas, 5000), _target, add(_calldata, 0x20), mload(_calldata), 0, 32)
    response := mload(0)
    switch iszero(succeeded)
    case 1 {
        revert(0, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

OpenZeppelin's one is the most generic and addresses contract upgrade scenario.  It forwards `msg.data` as is to called contracts, and returns what called contract returned.

MakerDAO's is also generic but it allows passing arbitrary `bytes` as parameters and packs returned value into `bytes` as well.

Simple version allows arbitrary `bytes` as parameters but only returns first 32 bytes of returned value.  It also ignores any data returned by failed delegate call.